# Different Python packages use different versions of the same DLL

Tags: python, python-3.x, dllimport, sapi, pyenchant

For my project I use `pyenchant` library for spell checking and `win32com.client.dispatch` to call `SAPI.SpVoice` for automatic voiceovers. I have some `Speech2Go` packages installed and all worked fine until I decided it's time to move my project to Python 3.9. The only thing preventing me to do it is the new version of `pyenchant`, which uses the same DLL as Speech2Go, but the different version. By trial and error I deduced that the DLL in question is `libstdc++-6.dll` and I cannot force one of these 2 programs to use the same version neither I can rename the DLL obviously.
But it turned out that this code does not work in Python 3.9:

```
import win32com.client
speaker = win32com.client.Dispatch("SAPI.SpVoice")

def speaktest(text):
    voices = speaker.GetVoices("Language = 409", 'Gender = Male')
    for voice in voices:
        desc = voice.GetDescription()
        if "Eric" in desc:
            speaker.Voice = voice
            speaker.Speak(text)
            break

if __name__ == '__main__':
    speaktest("Hello")
    import enchant
    from enchant.checker import SpellChecker
```

After `speaker.Speak(text)` is called, provided a Speech2Go voice is selected (named "Eric" in my case, because that's what I have installed), I cannot load pyenchant because of this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\PyCharm2021.2\scratches\scratch_9.py", line 21, in <module>
    import enchant
  File "C:\Plan Z Editor XXL\venv\lib\site-packages\enchant\__init__.py", line 81, in <module>
    from enchant import _enchant as _e
  File "C:\Plan Z Editor XXL\venv\lib\site-packages\enchant\_enchant.py", line 162, in <module>
    e = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(enchant_lib_path)
  File "C:\python39\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 452, in LoadLibrary
    return self._dlltype(name)
  File "C:\python39\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 374, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 127] The specified procedure could not be found

Process finished with exit code 1
```

If I call `speaktest` after importing pyenchant, this happens:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\PyCharm2021.2\scratches\scratch_9.py", line 22, in <module>
    speaktest("Hello")
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\PyCharm2021.2\scratches\scratch_9.py", line 16, in speaktest
    speaker.Speak(text)
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\gen_py\3.9\C866CA3A-32F7-11D2-9602-00C04F8EE628x0x5x4\ISpeechVoice.py", line 70, in Speak
    return self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(12, LCID, 1, (3, 0), ((8, 1), (3, 49)),Text
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2147221164), None)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

What CAN be a working solution is to use `multiprocessing` to handle the speaking and making sure `multiprocessing.freeze_support()` is called before importing pyenchant, thus making different Python instances load different versions of `libstdc++-6.dll`, but since I already have a code base around both pyEnchant and SAPI.SpVoice and it works the way it is, it's not a good idea to rewrite all the code just because these 2 libraries conflict with each other.

That's why I'm here asking whether there is a much simpler method of resolving this conflict without rewriting a large chunk of code?

Comment: Have you considered recompiling one or both of the libraries you're using, so they both link against the same C++ DLL? There's probably a good chance they both *can* work with the same DLL, they just weren't built that way in the packages you're using.